# Multiplying elements of an array in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm implementing a function to find the determinant of a Matrix. However, the following code presents the error: The right hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.

How do I resolve this?

```
export const matrixDeterminant = (a: number[][]) => {
  switch(a.length){
    case 2:
      const ad = a[0]*a[3]
      const bc = a[1]*a[2]
      return ad - bc
  }
}
```

Comment: you use array of arrays, so the a[0] is an array too

Answer (score 1):

You specify `a` as being an array of array of numbers but you treat it like it's a single array of numbers.

either:

```
export const matrixDeterminant = (a: number[]) => {
  switch(a.length){
    case 4: 
      const ad = a[0]*a[3];
      const bc = a[1]*a[2];
      return ad - bc;
  }
}

//call example
matrixDeterminant([1,2,3,4]);
```

or

```
export const matrixDeterminant = (a: number[][]) => {
  switch(a.length) { //you should check both rows and cols
    case 2:
      const ad = a[0][0]*a[1][1];
      const bc = a[0][1]*a[1][0];
      return ad - bc;
  }
}

//call example
matrixDeterminant([[1,2],[3,4]]);
```